# met memcachier(memcached) error when deploy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, memcached, memcachier

ruby version on Gemfile is v2.1.2 and rails version is 4.1.1

```
 ruby '2.1.2'
 gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
```

and there is like this.

```
gem "memcachier"
gem 'dalli'
```

I added memcachier add-on already. 
but when deploy my rails code to heroku, I met this error.

```
       Installing memcachier 0.0.2

       Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_af6f5b6f-490c-4015-8729-49c519b4a44c/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
       Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on Ubuntu and cyrus-sasl on Gentoo.
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_af6f5b6f-490c-4015-8729-49c519b4a44c/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby

       extconf failed, exit code 1

       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_af6f5b6f-490c-4015-8729-49c519b4a44c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/memcached-1.8.0 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_af6f5b6f-490c-4015-8729-49c519b4a44c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/memcached-1.8.0/gem_make.out
       Installing newrelic_rpm 3.8.1.221
       Installing kgio 2.9.2
       An error occurred while installing memcached (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install memcached -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

what is the reason of this and how can I avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. 
this is because of identity_cache gem. 
it has a dependancy on memcached. 
so I downgrade it to v0.1.0 and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-devel.x86_64
```